# Puppeteer on AWS EC2 Ubuntu with google-chrome-stable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I'm trying to run puppeteer on AWS to process some video. It's not the most obvious workflow, but I need to use a library that is written for the web, not Node.js.

I have worked through [several errors related to dependencies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md), [Blob URLs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3463), and [Chromium's capabilities with images and video](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video) and now I'm left with an entirely vague error with no clue on what else I need to fix.

Environment:

```
EC2 Instance: t2.medium Ubuntu 16.04
Original AMI: http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZUAKO
Node: v8.1.2
puppeteer: 1.5.0
google-chrome-stable: 71.0.3578.98-1
```

In my node.js app:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  headless: false,
});                  // ERROR IS THROWN BY puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', handleLogging(browser, exits, inputs.id));
await page.goto('http://ec2-my-instance.compute-1.amazonaws.com/analyzer');
```

Error:

```
{ Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/bitnami/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:285:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/home/bitnami/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:275:60)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
  cause: 
   Error: Failed to launch chrome!


   TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

       at onClose (/home/bitnami/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:285:14)
       at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/home/bitnami/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:275:60)
       at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12),
  isOperational: true }
```

Comment: Am I setting `executablePath` correctly? I'm a newbie with *nix.

Answer (score 3):

The executable path looks ok assuming chrome is actually there.

I was able to run your code on a similar EC2 instance by adding --single-process to args. Try the following args:

```
args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--single-process'],
```

Honestly, I'm not entirely sure why is it needed in EC2.

If you didn't set any display to the EC2 instance, you will also need to change to headless: true, otherwise you will get a similar error since chrome requires display to show.

** If I could I would put this in a comment rather than an answer as it's incomplete but sadly I don't have enough points.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this out once I'm back at my desk.